# Python String Editor

Tags: python, string

I am in a programming competition(I have no clue why, I barely know any advanced Python) because my teacher figured it would be a good idea. One of the practice projects is to create a string editor with 6 functions, which are Insert, Delete, Reverse, Update/Replace, Append, and Prepend a string. The syntax for the input should be something like:

```
computer I 3 BIT
```

with an output of

```
comper
```

So the first part is the string to edit, the second is the operation (I for insert, D for delete, R for reverse, etc). The problem is, the rest of the things are different. For I, D, and R, there are 4 parts. The 3rd is the starting point of the operation. The fourth is the string to be inserted for I, and the number of characters to delete for D, same for R. That I can handle. However, Update/Replace has 5 parts. The string, the modifier(U), the location to start, the number of characters to be replaced, and the substring to replace with.

Similarly, Append and Prepend have 3 parts. The original string, the modifier(A or P) and the substring to prepend or append.

So far, I have come up with the following code.

```
while True:
    Full_String = input("Please enter a string, modifier, start character, and iteration modifier: ")
    string, modifier, start, itermod = Full_String.split (" ")
    print (string)
    print (modifier)
    print (start)
    print (itermod)
```

The print commands are just for me to make sure the string is splitting correctly. However, whenever I try using the 3 or 5 arguments required of some operations, I get a ValueError. Normally, I would be able to add Try-Except blocks to catch the error, but I can't figure out how to do that without 2 levels of user input.

So how do I manage to get that down to one line of input no matter what? The input for each should look like the following:

Insert: String I 2 new

Delete: String D 2 3

Reverse: String R 2 3

Update/Replace: String U 2 3 new (the string length must be whatever the previous argument is, i.e. 3 new, 4 news, 5 great)

Append: String A New

Prepend: String P New

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use split, but keep the result in a single list: `result = Full_String.split(" ")`. Then you can refer to `result[3]` and `result[4]` etc, depending on the value of `result[0]`.

Comment: you need to take a look at *starred expressions*.

Comment: In general, it is helpful to append stack traces (of the ValueError in this case) to your question

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted clean code, I'd personally solve it like:

```
full_string = input("Please enter a string, modifier, start character, and iteration modifier:")
command = full_string.strip().split() # doesn't care about amount of whitespace used

if command[1] == 'I':
    # insert specific instructions
    string, _, start, itermod = command
    ...
...
elif command[1] == 'R':
    # replace specific
    string, _, index1, index2, new_string = command
...
```

Making a case for every string instruction.

You can probably also use the starred syntax as described in the comments:

```
string, command, *args = full_string.split(" ") # args is now a list of arguments
```

But this wont work in python2

**Update**: as noted by bruno desthuilliers, ideally you'd be using functions for every case. Although personally I would prefer to avoid constructions that cause extra complexity (like dictionairies/function pointers).

If extra functions are to be used, I'd probably do it like this myself:

```
def do_insert(string, start, itermod):
    ... program logic ...

def do_update(string, index1, index2, replacement):
    ... program logic ...

...

while True:
    full_string = input("Please enter a string, modifier, start character, and iteration modifier:")

    # doesn't care about amount of whitespace used
    command = full_string.strip().split() 

    # split the command into string, modifier and additional variable args
    string, modifier, extra_args = command[0], command[1], command[2:]

    if modifier == 'I':
        do_insert(string, *extra_args)  
    elif modifier == 'D':
        do_delete(string, *extra_args)
    elif modifier == 'U':
        do_update(string, *extra_args)
    ...
```

The `*extra_args` here will insert the elements of `extra_args` as arguments. 
For instance calling `func(a, b, *[1,2,3])` will be translated to `func(a, b, 1, 2, 3)`

Comment: A "clean" code would abstract out the argument parsing so the main loop don't have to care about it...  And indeed the star syntax won't work with Python 2.

Comment: I agree that ideally, methods should be used. Although I feel for this relatively simple purpose, a simpler set up would be better, especially if you're just a beginner. Although elegant, your solution might be a bit complex to start with.

Comment: "methods" (well, classes etc) are not the only available abstraction... just using basic stuff (functions, dicts, lists, tuples) you can already make the main loop totally generic wrt/ operations specificities, cf my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The input content and how it should be parsed depends on the command, so you should have one parser per command. You can do this using a dict mapping the command ("I", "D", "R" etc) to the parser function:

```
def parse_insert(args):
   # code to parse arguments for an insert
   return {
      "start": args[0], 
      "itermod": args[1]
   }



def parse_delete(args):
   # code to parse argumenst for a delete
   # cf example above

# etc

PARSERS = {
    "I" : parse_insert, 
    "D" : parse_delete, 
    # etc  
}


def main():
    while True:
         full_string = input("Please enter a string, modifier, start character, and iteration modifier: ")
         parts = full_string.split (" ")
         line = parts[0]
         parser = PARSERS[parts[1]]
         op_args = parser(parts[2:])
```

You'll probably need something similar for operations, ie:

```
def do_delete(line, start, itermod):
    # code here


def do_insert(line, ....)
   # idem


OPERATIONS = {
    "D" : do_delete,
    "I": do_insert,
    # etc
}



def main():
    while True:
         full_string = input("Please enter a string, modifier, start character, and iteration modifier: ")
         parts = full_string.split (" ")
         line = parts[0]
         opid = parts[1]
         parser = PARSERS[opid]
         op_args = parser(parts[2:]) 
         print(line, opid, op_args)
         op = OPERATORS[opid]
         result = op(line, **op_args)
         print(result)
```

This still requires some error handling but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix your splitting problem and you can write the rest of your program yourself. `split()` takes a second argument that tell it how many times it may split. Your edit commands have three fixed arguments, followed by stuff that varies. So you could split into at most three parts, inspect the command, and continue as appropriate:

```
string, cmd, rest = full_string.split(" ", 2)
if cmd == "I":
    start, toinsert = rest.split(" ", 1)  # `toinsert` string could contain spaces?
elif cmd == "R":
    <etc.>
```

Alternately, you could collect the variable-length part into a list, to be interpreted later. But this is non-ideal if the inserted string is allowed to contain spaces, since they'll cause extra breaks in the string.

```
string, cmd, start, *rest = full_string.split()
```

Here, `rest` becomes a list with the extra arguments (if any), and you can again reassign them based on the command.

```
if cmd == "I":
    toinsert = rest[0]
elif cmd == "R":
    <etc.>
```